# Generate State Machine graph from VHDL code?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

Is there any quite good tool to generate State Machine graph from VHDL code? I'm using Xilinx ISE Webpack. Cheers!

Comment: A state chart can get ugly very quickly. What kind of output would you like to see ideally? What kind of input are you providing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Active HDL](http://www.aldec.com/activehdl/) has a feature called "[Code2Graphics](http://www.aldec.com/Technologies/Technology.aspx?technologyid=60b5427a-ee34-4be3-bd3a-78417398041c)" which supports this.
Additionally, some synthesis tools (typically ones you would have to pay for) also support this.

Note that an RTL view is more commonly available in synthesis tools (such as XST).

Answer (score 1):

Modelsim SE (and DE?) have these kind of things.  But, not for free :-(